# xsd - Assert condition checking all descendants

Tags: validation, xsd, assert, xsd-1.1

I have a following xml:

```
<request>
  <resource>
    <regime>payed</regime>
  </resource>
  <user>
    <contract>
      <data>
        <discount>true</discount>
        <priceInPercents>0</priceInPercents>
      </data>
      <data>
        <discount>false</discount>
        <priceInPercents>20</priceInPercents>
      </data>
      <data>
        <discount>false</discount>
        <priceInPercents>0</priceInPercents>
      </data>
   </contract>
  </user>
</request>
```

The XML follows a XSD file, in which I'd like to add a condition, that checks following: if the regime is 'payed', then any priceInPercents cannot be '0', unless the discount element in that particular data element is 'true'. (Possible values for regime is only 'payed' or 'free'). I am trying to do that using assert on the level of request in the following way:

```
<assert test="./resource/regime/text() = 'free' 
              or ./user/contract
                 /data[discount=false]
                 /priceInPercents != 0 
              or ./user/contract
                 /data[priceInPercents = 0]
                 /discount = true "/>
```

In this case, validator says its OK, because the second part of the condition is fulfilled in the second case and the third part is fullfilled in the first case. The third case does not match any of the conditions, but it does not matter, because assert already found a match. I need to rewrite the XPath to check the pattern for all data elements, but I really don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly, the condition you want to enforce is that within a given request, either

- `resource/regime eq 'free'`, or
- for every `user/contract/data` element, either

  - `priceInPercents` is non-zero, or
  - `discount eq 'true'`

One way to handle this is to reverse the Boolean polarity of the second main disjunct, and say "there is no `data` element with both `priceInPercents eq '0' and discount eq 'false'`.  You could say that this way:

```
<assert test="./resource/regime eq 'free' 
              or not(./user/contract
                 /data[discount eq 'false' and priceInPercents eq 0])"/>
```

It may be a little easier to follow if you use a universally quantified expression; these take the form `every ... satisfies ...`.  In this case, one possible formulation would be:

```
<assert test="./resource/regime = 'free' 
              or every $d in ./user/contract/data
                 satisfies
                 ($d/discount eq 'true' 
                 or $d/priceInPercents ne 0)"/>
```